# how to delete and re-add a class with every click

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to delete and re-add a class with every click ? Implemented through setTimeout but it seems to me there are more correct options.

```
 $(".btn-test").on("click", function () {

  function addAnimateForBorder(y) {
    $(".data-engwords").removeClass("active-border-words");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $(".data-engwords").addClass("active-border-words");
    }, 10);
  }

  addAnimateForBorder();

  $(".data-ruswords").html("");
})
```

Comment: can you add the corresponding CSS and HTML?

Comment: Use `toggleClass("active-border-words")` for that purpouse. If you then want to delete that class 10ms after, it isn't bad using setTimeout in my opinion

Comment: Please confirm:  your requirement is to remove a class on click and then immediately(?) add it back again?  10ms won't even register to the user as anything other than a flicker (unless there's something in the css).   Why did you think you needed the setTimeout?

Comment: I asked which option would be better and correct.